# Criteria builder error during update query: BinaryArithmeticOperation did not match expected type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I am trying to execute the next SQL using hibernate criteria builder:

```
update account set balance = balance + 500;
```

Here is my query building code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<JBCAccount> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(JBCAccount.class);
Root root = update.from(JBCAccount.class);

update.set("balance", cb.sum(root.get("balance"), amount));

getEntityManager().createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
```

Also I've tried:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<JBCAccount> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(JBCAccount.class);
Root root = update.from(JBCAccount.class);

ParameterExpression<Long> amountExpression = cb.parameter(Long.class);

update.set("balance", cb.sum(root.get("balance"), amountExpression));

getEntityManager().createQuery(update)
    .setParameter(amountExpression, amount).executeUpdate();
```

Both executions produce the next error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.BinaryArithmeticOperation@53e0be2d] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.BinaryArithmeticOperation@53e0be2d] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]] with root cause
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.BinaryArithmeticOperation@53e0be2d] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
```

The balance type in the MySQL database is: `balance bigint UNSIGNED`.
`amount` variable in the code has type `Long`.
`balance` property of `JBCAccount` is `Long`.

I also tried to recreate a MySQL schema with `balance bigint` (i.e. without `UNSIGNED`). The same problem still.

What am I missing?

Comment: And which type is `balance` property in `JBCAccount` entity?

Comment: It is `Long` as well

Comment: Try to use [`CriteriaBuilder#sumAsLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#sumAsLong-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-) and/or substitute the first arguement of `set`, i.e. `balance` string, with a `Path` expression like `root.get("balance")`

Comment: And/or cast the Path expression using [`CriteriaBuilder#toLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#toLong-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-)

Comment: Also, specify the type in Path expression with `Path<Long> balance = root.<Long> get("balance")`

Comment: @perissf Thank you a lot! You last suggestion helped! I've changed the line to the next one: `update.set((Path<?>) root.<Long>get("balance"), cb.sum(root.<Long>get("balance"), amount));` and it now works. If you make the answer I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify that the path attribute refers to a Long:

```
update.set((Path<?>) root.<Long>get("balance"), cb.sum(root.<Long>get("balance"), amount));
```